# Controller not found trying PHPUnit tests at CakePHP 2.0

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, controller, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to run PHPUnit test at CakePHP 2.0.
There's no problem with my model tests but when i try to run my Controllers tests i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/Controller/AppController.php on line 7`
```

What's going on?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you always need to properly define the used classes (which you want to extend) - even in your controllers:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {}
```

you miss the App::uses statement.

Comment: No, all controllers work well. I have that line in my code. The problem is only when i try to Test them with PHPUnit tests.

Comment: the controllers will always work well (from the application itself). so you are 100% sure that the App::uses() statement is in the app controller? and you don't use the Controller class itself before the AppController class is called? I am pretty sure that is your problem. You can work around by adding the same statement to your test case - at the very top. But it would be cleaner to fix the issue with the correct include order.

Comment: You are completely right Mark :) Thanks for all and sorry for my previous reply, i didn't read it well.